# query get faster when column size decrease

Tags: sql, sql-server, size

There is a table that contains column which is varchar(1500). This table called from procedure. When I execute it takes 3 second. 
Then i decreased column size to varchar(1000). Then it takes 1 second.
I could not find any explanation. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  What is the query/procedure you are running?

Comment: I am using 2008 R2 and running SP.